# Требуется ли запятая, если в начале стоит «В скором времени»?

Tags: запятые

«В скором времени с брата снимут все обвинения(,) и он станет свободным человеком, как всегда и мечтал». 
Нужна там запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ***в скором времени*** общая часть для простых предложений в ССП, то запятой нет.

В скором времени с брата снимут все обвинения и (в скором времени) он станет свободным человеком, как всегда и мечтал.

Comment: Спасибо!) Я думала, что запятая там значит следствие, но, видимо, стоит получше разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: Но ведь там есть союз И, значит, это не бессоюзное, а сложносочинённое

Answer (score 1):

***(1) В скором времени с брата снимут все обвинения, //  и (2) он станет свободным человеком, (3) как (он) всегда и мечтал.***

А я бы поставила запятую, паузу тоже можно обозначить.

Фактически здесь три предложения и **два смысловых блока.**

Поэтому обстоятельство ***в скором времени***  скорее можно отнести к  предложению 1, а союз И относится к предложениям 2 и 3.

В предложении вполне можно выделить **две смысловые ситуации** (скоро с брата снимут все обвинения; он станет свободным, как всегда мечтал), а не сводить распространенную информацию к ситуации одной.